# How can I reserve a fixed buffer size in OpenCV Mat?

Tags: c++, opencv, memory-management, mat

I am rewriting some legacy code that does matrix operations on doubles using a raw C-style array. Since the code already has a dependency on OpenCV somewhere else, I want to use the `cv::Mat` class instead.

The specific code that bothers me works on square matrixes from size 1*1 to N*N. It does so by allocating an N*N buffer and uses a subset of it for smaller matrixes.

```cpp
double* buf = new double[NxN];
for (int i = 1; i < N; ++i) {
    // Reuse buf to create a i*i matrix and perform matrix operations
    ...

}
delete[] buf;
```

Basically, I want to replace that code to use `cv::Mat` objects in the loop instead. Problem is, the code requires a lot of loop iterations (there are nested loops and so on) and there are too many allocations/deallocations if I just use the naïve and clean approach. Therefore, I want to reserve the size of my matrix object beforehand and resize it for each iteration. This would ideally look like this:

```cpp
cv::Mat m;
m.reserveBuffer(N * N * sizeof(double));
for (int i = 1; i < N; ++i) {
    m = cv::Mat(i, i, CV_64F);
    // Perform matrix operations on m
    ...

}
```

But in my understanding this would simply drop the previous instance of `m` and then allocate a i*i matrix. What would the right approach be?

Comment: You don't resize, you allocate one Mat, and then create views ([ROI](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.3/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a4272fce43d7405603fbb5e5f52580e57)s) of that Mat to represent those smaller submatrices.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a submatix header for your buffer using [`cv::Mat::operator()`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#id6). Pass a `cv::Rect` for ROI you want to process in current loop iteration (`{0, 0, i, i}` in your case)  and it will return a view of your buffer region as another `cv::Mat` instance. It will not allocate new buffer but will refer to original buffer data instead.

```
cv::Mat m(N, N, CV_64FC1);
for (int i = 1; i < N; ++i) {
    cv::Mat subM = m({0, 0, i*i});
    // Perform matrix operations on "subM"
    // Modifying "subM" will modify "m" buffer region that "subM" represents
}
```

Note that `subM` will not [be continious](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-iscontinuous), so you will need to process it row by row if you do any raw buffer processing.

Comment: Interesting take, it's elegant! Is there a (measurable) performance hit in using a non-continuous matrix, for example on matrix multiplications? The original goal was improving the performance and making the code more readable.

Comment: @OlivierDesenfans It depends on how you iterate the raw buffers. Any way it won't decrease performance too much. See performance comparison of per-pixel data access approaches on continious and not continious buffers here: https://longstryder.com/2014/07/which-way-of-accessing-pixels-in-opencv-is-the-fastest/.

Comment: @OlivierDesenfans measure your previous implementaion (in legacy code) and this implementation execution time to see how performmance changed.